# Drawing in my custom view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, drawing

i added a custom view and want to draw an inner smaller circle, outer bigger circle and and perpendicular line. the `drawRect:` method in my class looks like this.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    float height = rect.size.height;
    float width = rect.size.width;
    CGContextTranslateCTM(myContext, 0.0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(myContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGPoint middle = CGPointMake(width/2, height/2);
    UIBezierPath *innerCirclePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:middle radius:25 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:YES];
    [innerCirclePath setLineWidth:2];
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [innerCirclePath stroke];
    UIBezierPath *outerCirclePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:middle radius:120 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:NO];
    [outerCirclePath setLineWidth:2];
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    [outerCirclePath stroke];
    UIBezierPath *xAxis = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [xAxis moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height/2 - 150)];
    [xAxis addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height/2 + 150)];
    [xAxis closePath];
    [[UIColor grayColor] setStroke];
    [xAxis setLineWidth:2];
    [xAxis stroke];
}
```

Now I do get the circles, both outer and inner but there is no perpendicular line that I wanted. Why is it not getting drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using these two lines to set up the path for your “perpendicular line”:

```
[xAxis moveToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height/2 - 150)];
[xAxis addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(width, height/2 + 150)];
```

The problem is that the X coordinate of both points is the right edge of your view.  Perhaps you want it to be at the center of your view:

```
CGFloat xMid = CGRectGetMidX(rect);
[xAxis moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xMid, height/2 - 150)];
[xAxis addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(xMid, height/2 + 150)];
```

Comment: shit, yeah. man i feel stupid haha. i should go off to sleep now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What color is the background of your view? You should make sure it's not too close to `greyColor` or you won't see it even if it's there.

Comment: na its white and i even changed the UIColor to black, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try alter these two lines

```
[xAxis setLineWidth:2];
[[UIColor grayColor] setStroke];
```

Comment: did that, still couldn't draw.